# JavaScript convert [object Object] to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am implementing a token based authentication and I need to access the token I have set when i check if the user is authenticated.

I am using this method to check if the user is authenticated:

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.headers['authorization'];
    console.log(token);
    if (token) {
        req.token = token;
        next();
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
}
```

The `console.log(token)` prints out `[object Object]` how can I convert this to a json object?

The token is generated with the jsonwebtoken module this way:

```
jwt.sign({ user_id: user.user_id }, config.app.secretKey, { expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 }, (err, token) => {
    return res.send(token);
});
```

Comment: Try  `console.log(req);`

Comment: If you change `console.log(token)` to `console.log(typeof token)` what does the console the show? `string` or `object`?

Comment: @t.niese appearently `string`

Comment: Then the value stored in `req.headers['authorization']` is a string with the contents `[object Object]`. Due to that the problem is at an earlier stage in the whole process. Somewhere the `authorization` header is set incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the string `"[object Object]"` doesn't have enough information to recreate back the original object. You'll have to debug the logic and find out why `req.headers['authorization']` has such value in the first place.